# Simple sequence $\left( \frac{1}{6n^{2} + 1} \right) _{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ convergence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I wish to claim $\left( \frac{1}{6n^{2} + 1} \right) _{n \in \mathbb{N}} \longrightarrow  0$ in a rigorous way.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. I need to work out $N \in \mathbb{N}$ that shows convergence, i.e. satisfies $n \geq N \implies \lvert a_{n} - a \rvert < \epsilon$. The beginning of the hunt for $N$ is clear:
$$\lvert \frac{1}{6N^{2} + 1} - 0 \rvert = \frac{1}{6N^{2} + 1}$$ 
Hence the requirement
$$\frac{1}{6N^{2} + 1} < \epsilon$$ 
Now is the part where my solution diverges from the solution in the book. I say:
$$6N^{2} + 1 > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$$ 
$$N > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon} - \frac{1}{6}}$$
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $n \geq N$. Then,
$$n \geq N \implies n > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon} - \frac{1}{6}} \implies \frac{1}{6n^{2} + 1} < \epsilon \implies \lvert a_n - 0 \rvert < \epsilon$$.

However, the book's solution takes $N > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon}}$.

Now, I understand that $\epsilon$ is usually small and substracing $\frac{1}{6}$ in the expression makes marginal difference. Even if $\epsilon$ is easy and large (e.g. $\epsilon = \frac{1}{10}$) and the difference between $\sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon}}$ and $\sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon} - \frac{1}{6}}$ is noticable ($\approx 1.29$ and $\approx 1.22$, respectively), the answer is still rounded to natural numbers (convergence at $n=2$ in both cases).

Do I have some errors? If not, then how can I know if I can drop something and still have the same result?

Comment: Both are correct, but book takes that value because it is simpler.  In fact,  since $\sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon} - \frac{1}{6}} < \sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon}}$, Your solution implies book's.

Comment: The book solution works when $\epsilon \geq 1$, and yours depends on a negative square root. Can you figure out in which step you missed something from here?

Comment: Your proof doesn't hold for all $ \ \varepsilon > 0 $, in matter of fact $ \forall \varepsilon > 1$.

Comment: You could choose $N = \begin{cases} 0&\text{if } \epsilon \ge 1\\\sqrt{\frac 1{6{\epsilon}}-\frac 16}&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.  But no-one ever said you had to find the most efficient $N$..  Merely that you had to find *AN* $N$.  ANd the book did.

Comment: 1)"Now, I understand that ϵ is usually small and substracing 16 in the expression makes marginal difference." Who cares? The difference could be $10$ billion and it still be true. In $n>N+10$billion$>N$ then $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. 2)"the answer is still rounded to natural numbers" so the $\frac 16$ isn't needed. Doesnt hurt(almost) but isn't needed. 3)"I understand that ϵ is usually small"... yeah but hypothetically it might not be. It *might* be bigger than $1$.  But you can dismiss this with wave.

Comment: "how can I know if I can drop something and still have the same result?" The only thing you need is that $n > N$ so there is no upper limit to what $N$ may be. You can round up but not down.  And if you are doing something like $6n^5 -39n^4 +7n^3+2n^2-3n + 27 > \frac 1{\epsilon}$ you sure as heck want to round. Assume $n>39$ so $n^5>39n^4>7n^3>2n^2>3n>27$ so $6n^5 > \frac 1{\epsilon}$.

Comment: BTW when you start the hunt it should be for boundaries for $n$. Not to solve for a *specific* $N$.  Place $n$ in and get a limit well $n > thing$ and figure $N \ge thing$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a (serious) error but you didn't take into account what happens if $\epsilon > 1$ and $\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16 < 0$.

But then a simple argument that $\frac {1}{6n^2+1}$ is always less than $1$ so that need not be considered.

SO you didn't make any serious error.  But neither did the book.

Notice if $n > N_{\text{book's}}=\sqrt{\frac 1{6\epsilon}}$ then $n > N_{\text{yours}}\sqrt{\frac 1{6\epsilon}-\frac 16}$ and so if you were correct so was the book.  So would I be if I choose $N = 10^{5,000}\cdot \frac 1{\sqrt \epsilon}$.

None of us were under any obligation to find the *smallest* $N$.

=====

Actually I suppose it *is* an error.  But a small one.

At  $6N^2 + 1 >\frac 1\epsilon$ the step you skipped is

$N^2 >\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16$.  But you can't take the square root of both side unless both sides are positive.  But as we want $N > 0$ we can do one of two things.  1) we can be thorough or 2) we can be heavy or 3) we can be practical.

1)  we can do something like or equivalent to saying.

$N^2 >\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16$ so

$N^2 \ge \max (\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16, 0)$ and

$N \ge \max (\sqrt{\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16},0)$.

or

2)  We dont need to smallest $N$ so

We want $N > \frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16 $ and we can get that by setting.

$N > \frac 1{6\epsilon} >\frac 1{6\epsilon} - \frac 16$.

And $N > \sqrt\frac 1{6\epsilon}$.

3) We can point out,  $|a_n - L |< \epsilon_2$ for a small $\epsilon_2$ then $|a_n- L| < \epsilon_2 < \epsilon_1$ for a a larger $\epsilon_1$.  So we may assume without any loss of generality that $\epsilon$ is small enough so that $\frac 1{6\epsilon^2} -\frac 16 > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Why over complicate it? For all $n\geq 1,$ it follows that $6n^2+1>6n^2>n^2\geq n$. Hence,
$$
\frac{1}{6n^2+1}<\frac{1}{n}.
$$
Let $\epsilon>0$. By Archimedes' principle, there exists $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$. Then for all $n\geq N$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{6n^2+1}<\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon.
$$
Maybe it's good for your skill set to practice playing around with square roots and inequalities, but it's also important to learn to see certain bounds.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by Archimedes' principle here? I reckon is a concept in physics, how can it relate to existence of $N$ s.t. $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$?

Comment: Btw yes I see that $6N^2 + 1 > 6N^2 > N^2 > N$ follows, and it's easier to say that $n > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, but this seems crude. Say epsilon is 1e-6 then we guarantee convergence above million iterations, while only 409 are enough when using $n > \sqrt{\frac{1}{6\epsilon}}$. Still, useful answer I see your point thanks again

Comment: What you pointed out is why I added a comment to my answer indicating that it may be a good skill set to look for tighter bounds. To just answer the question, my way is definitely the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

The choice of N can be made after a possible improvement in order to simplify the calculations. For example by noticing that: $$\forall n \in \mathbb N , n \geq  1 \Rightarrow 6n^2+1 \geq n^2 $$ we have $$n \geq  1 \Rightarrow |u_n|=\frac{1}{6n^2+1} \leq  \frac{1}{n^2}$$
To have $|u_n| < \varepsilon $, it suffices that : $\frac{1}{n^2} < \epsilon$, that is to say: $n > \frac{1}{\sqrt \varepsilon} $, then by taking $N= 1+\left\lfloor \frac{1}{\sqrt \varepsilon}\right\rfloor$ we have :$$\forall n \in \mathbb N, n \geq  N  \Rightarrow |u_n| < \varepsilon $$